# Найти число, которое является некоторой степенью двойки

Tags: python, математика

Программа должна ввести с консоли натуральное число `n` и найти число следующее за `n`, которое является некоторой степенью двойки. Например, вводим,  `7`, оно не может являться степенью двойки, прибавляем `1` - получаем `8` (это `2` в `3` степени).

Вот мой код, который не даёт желаемого результата:

```py
n = int(input())
z = n
x = 2
active = True
while active:
   for i in range(1, n):
      if z == x**i:
         active = False
   z += 1
z = n 
print(n)
```

Comment: `print(2 ** int(input()).bit_length())`

Comment: @extrn, элегантно! почему бы не оформить это ответом?

Comment: @MaxU и так много ответов, чтобы из за десятка букв новый писать :)

Comment: @extrn дело не в количестве ответов, а в качестве. Оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант решения:

```py
print(2 ** int(input()).bit_length())
```

Comment: по-моему, это самый элегантный вариант решения)

Comment: @MaxU Есть еще классический способ выделить старший бит за log(log(n)), т.е. за логарифм от числа бит, но он больше подходит для типов с фиксированным размером. Т.е. не для python.

Answer (score 6):

Для того чтобы проверить, является ли число степенью двойки, можно воспользоваться условием `n & (n - 1) == 0`:

[image: Побитовое "И"]

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    n = 7  # int(input())

    while not (n & (n - 1) == 0):
        n += 1

    print(n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
8
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно немного вспомнить математику и обойтись без циклов , воспользовавшись логарифмом:

```
import math

def next_pow_of_two(n):
     assert n > 0, "expecting a natural [n]"
     return 2 ** int(math.log2(n) + 1)
```

Тесты:

```
In [87]: next_pow_of_two(7)
Out[87]: 8

In [88]: next_pow_of_two(8)
Out[88]: 16

In [89]: next_pow_of_two(65)
Out[89]: 128

In [90]: next_pow_of_two(3)
Out[90]: 4

In [91]: next_pow_of_two(257)
Out[91]: 512

In [92]: next_pow_of_two(255)
Out[92]: 256
```

Answer (score 4):

Прежде всего, когда вы в конце программы сделаете

```
print(n)
```

то вы напрасно исчисляли `z`. Очевидно вы хотели

```
print(z)
```

Во вторых, после нахождения `z`, вы его всё равно в части

```
         active = False
   z += 1
```

еще раз увеличиваете — значит, что вы должны выводит не `z`, но `z - 1`:

```
print(z - 1)
```

Tакже ваша программа хочет только правку в последней команде - т.е. она будет иметь вид

```
n = int(input())
z = n
x = 2
active = True
while active:
   for i in range(1, n):
      if z == x**i:
         active = False
   z += 1
print(z - 1)
```

(я тоже убрал вашу предпоследнюю — лишнюю — команду).